# Remove vertical line between icon and header in WPF MenuItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to remove the vertical line between icon and header in MenuItem:

[image]

I've managed to find that I should use Blend for that and edit menu item in it. So when I right-click on the first MenuItem and select Edit Template -> Edit a Copy... it shows me the template with PART_Popup in it. The rectangle in the PART_Popup is what I need to remove:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle"
           Fill="#FFD7D7D7"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="29,2,0,2"
           Width="1"/>
```

To fix it in CSS, I would probably do something like .Menu .Rectangle { display: none; }. Is there a way to do something like this in WPF? Anything like

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template.PART_Popup.Rectangle.Display"
                Value="none"/>
    </Style>
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the Blend - Edit Template approach is not just a way to understand the existing template, but it is really the right approach to make such changes. Just comment out or remove the unwanted rectangles and apply the customized style to your menu.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <!-- Some other stuff -->

        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="-2" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF959595" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Margin="1,0" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Rectangle Fill="#F1F1F1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,2" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Width="28"/>

                            <!-- Part to be removed -->

                            <!--
                            <Rectangle Fill="#E2E3E3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                            <Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                            -->
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>

   <!-- More other stuff -->
```

You have to repeat the same change for `SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <!-- Same change as above -->
```

As you see, the rectangles have no name and no binding to control properties, so changing them without a new template might be possible but it's not the best way.

You can apply the style (lets call it `MenuItemStyle1`) to all menu items of a menu, by making it a local implicit style:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle1}"/>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <MenuItem Header="MenuItem">
        <MenuItem Header="MenuItem"/>
        <MenuItem Header="MenuItem">
            <MenuItem Header="SubMenu"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```